# Scaffold-DbContext : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbSoP.png)I am experience this issue on my Nuget console, while running this command below. Please help me further thanks.

```
scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer-OutputDir Models
```

Comment: The worse part i am following this thread even to Github, i am now trying to amend this command to scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer-Verbose. Still no luck does not build successfully

Comment: But if i re ran the command as this scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  -OutputDir Models/Verbose. Im getting this error scaffold-DBContext : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you scaffold command. 
You can use -ContextDir (PMC) and --context-dir (CLI) to scaffold the DbContext class into a separate directory from the entity type classes.

Try following command in PMC.

Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Data -OutputDir Models

Also check your Models folder in project root directory with all folder access [read/edit] rights.check single space  **-OutputDir Models**

You can find more detail on this link [Reverse Engineering (Scaffolding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding)

Answer (score 0):

Check you code especially for space characters etc. you have to put a space character **before** *-OutputDir* word...

Your code should be like this:

scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.**SqlServer -OutputDir** Models